# autospec with multiple versions of Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-1.9

I've installed Ruby 1.9.1 alongside Ruby 1.8.6 on my Mac OS X Leopard using the `prefix` and `program-suffix` options so that I can run Ruby 1.9 stuff by issuing ruby19, irb19, gem19, etc. commands.

I've installed the corresponding gems and can run `rake19 spec` to execute my rspec tests but when I run autospec I get:

> loading autotest/rails_rspec
>   Autotest style autotest/rails_rspec doesn't seem to exist. Aborting.

I'm assuming there's a conflict between the ZenTest/rspec gems for Ruby 1.9 and Ruby 1.8.6 but not sure how resolve the issue. Has anyone ran into this and can offer some advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess it is a ZenTest incompatibility with Ruby 1.9.

It looks from [isitruby19.com](http://isitruby19.com/zentest) that you aren't the only one having trouble with it. Fewer people are having trouble with rspec (and their issues are failing tests, not inability to run), so I'd be inclined to say it's ZenTest.

Personally, I'm just staying away from 1.9 because I have too many commercial development projects on the go. Hopefully I'll be able to help more with something like Rails 3 releases.